# Error: [: status_code: integer expression expected in bash

Tags: bash, shell, integer, devops

I am a beginner at programming in Unix enviroment and I am facing some difficulties at start. can you help me out in this.

````
echo "ES Service getting ready, it may take few mins."
status_code=-1
while [ "status_code" -ne 200 ]
do
    status_code=$(curl -k --write-out %{http_code} --connect-timeout 10---max-time 20 --silent --output /dev/null $ES_HOST)
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done
```strong text
````

Comment: Looks like you've missed $ in `[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `-ne` expects an integer expression, and `"status_code"` isn't an integer, is it? It's a string.

`$status_code` would be the integer you're looking for.